# SQL QUERY for time totalisation calculation

Tags: sql, time, integral

This is an example of dataset: [image: table and graph].
I am looking for an SQL query that calculates the integral of the curve defined by the example data.
Since the value of the curve is a boolean (0-1), calculating the integral using seconds would also result in the value of time in seconds that the pump ran.
The initial interval would be 00:00:00.000 and the final 23:59:59.000.
I guess I have to scroll the data from top to bottom, check the next or previous value, evaluate and do the time differences, but I have no idea how to do it.
In my example: from midnight until 2 o'clock the value is 0, from 2 o'clock until 4 o'clock the pump is on so 04:00:06-02:00:07=7,199s, then it is on from 15 o'clock until 17 o'clock so 17:00:04-15:00:04=7200s, and then it is on from 22:00:03 until 23:59:59 because there is no 0 value.
Basically I should add up the number of seconds where the value is at 1 until the next 0 or 23:59:59.
In a day I might have more than 10000 samplings at different times, not necessarily hourly.
The cursor could scroll through the data, if next is =1 then seconds[date(next)-date(cursor)], if next is =0 do not calculate.

Comment: Please update your question to show the result you want to achieve, based on the source data you've provided. However, your data appears to show that you have a "1" record for every hour that the pump is running - so can't you just sum them?

Comment: the useful result could be the number of seconds calculated.
The example is of a reduced hourly data set, in a day I might have more than 10000 samplings at different times, not necessarily hourly.
Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what "the useful result could be the number of seconds calculated" means. As I said in my previous comment, please update the question with the result you want to achieve based on the sample data you've provided - and explain how the result is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LAG()` to get the previous sample. Then computing the area under the curve should be trivial.

For example:

```
select t.*,
  pumpon * (localcol - lag(localcol) over(order by localcol)) as area
from t
```

The total area under the curve could be:

```
select
  sum(pumpon *
    (localcol - lag(localcol) over(order by localcol))
  ) as total_area
from t
```

Comment: thanks, I saw that LAG and LEAD do not work in SQL2008.<br>
In SQL 2019: The first query works fine, however with the SUM function I get error "Msg 4109, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate."